# Can't use string ("1") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use

Tags: perl

I am trying to check if a hash key exists, for example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my $h={a=>1,b=>2};

dump($h);

if (exists $h->{a}{b}) {
  say "Key exists.";
}
dump($h);
```

This gives:

```
{ a => 1, b => 2 }
Can't use string ("1") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at ./p.pl line 12.
```

What is the reason for this error message?

Comment: use `ref` to check for hashref - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267706/why-do-i-get-cant-use-string-as-a-hash-ref-error-when-i-try-to-access-a-hash

Comment: Kudos for using [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump).  Just a note, the module exports the `dd` method by default, which you can use to print to STDOUT.  The `dump` method is meant for serializing a data structure to a variable.  However, when called in a void context it does behave the same as `dd`, which I didn't know until observing your usage here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$h->{a}{b}` implies that value of `$h->{a}` is hashref, and you want to check if key `b` for it exists.

Since `$h->{a}` is simple scalar (`1`) it can not be used as hashref (`use strict` prevents it), and thus message `Can't use string (“1”) as a HASH ref`